# set waypoints for robot

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
Could be rviz (or any over utils) used for interactive placing route points of the robot?
Thank you!

**UPD** it seems possible to write the plugin for rviz (although it is strange that this has not - the problem seems standard). But the documentation on writing rviz plugins doesnt available :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12036/set-waypoints-for-robot/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2011-11-21

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-12-07**:
I think the reason that there isn't is that rviz is mainly a display tool. It is currently undergoing a lot of changes including plugin API. see: http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Planning/rviz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about using Interactive Markers? -> http://www.ros.org/wiki/interactive_markers

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2011-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-12-23**:
i've think about it )

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you looking for the "2D Nav Goal" Button at the top?

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-11-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-11-22**:
yes :) i think it is :)

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-11-22**:
OK, it gives you only the first point of a route. I think the problem is that you need something to execute the waypoints.

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-11-21**:
sure - but as i could see it using only for set movment direction. I want to set several point of robot route points.